# Alignment of HTML form with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I trying to create a login form. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myfiles/myfunc.php"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything in the above form spans to whole screen. I want to keep it in center and not too wide. I tried style = "width:auto;". This restricts the width but the stuff becomes left aligned. Also I want to add some color to background. I am very new to web-programming. So my question may sound trivial. But I searched on web and couldn't find any relevant example

Comment: You can use `max-width`. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hp5898yL/)

Comment: The problem is that the content isn't wrapped in a row/column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your content inside a row/column and offsetting it.

To get a general idea of how the Bootstrap grid works, check out [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label> 
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"/>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" />&nbsp;Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a small snippet from the Bootstrap documentation that explains the grid system.

> Grid systems are used for creating page layouts through a series of
>   rows and columns that house your content. Here's how the Bootstrap
>   grid system works:
>
> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding. Use
>   rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
>
> Content should be placed
>   within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting your form in this div :

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
  Your form
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your bootstrap container?

```
<div class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: Thanks. The code I pasted above didn't work by making this change.

Answer (score 0):

Better wrap this form with bootstraps columns, since you are using bootstrap anyway.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
  Your form
</div>
```

Another option is to style the form or better use a wrapper div.

```
.form-signin{
    width: 200px; //set a fixed width, so the container can be cenetered
    margin: 100px auto; //centers the form in the bootstrap container
    padding: 20px 10px; //add some padding so you can actually see things like bg color
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm- col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">

            <form class="form-signin">
              <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
              <div class="form-group">  
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group">  
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              </div>     
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <body>
```